# Clarification of inheritance of methods

Tags: c#

An interviewer asked me the question below

```
public class A
{
   public string GetName()
   {
      return "A";
   }
}

public class B : A
{
   public string GetName()
   {
      return "B";
   }
}
public class C : B()
{
   public string GetName
   {
      return "C";
   }
}
```

What are the outputs of

```
A a = new A();
a.GetName();

a = new B();
a.GetName();

a = new C();   
a.GetName();
```

I said all will give "A". Then he said i need to correct my basics.

Comment: You are correct. They all produce "A".

Comment: Sounds like your interviewer was wrong? But you should have been able to argue your viewpoint effectively. If this were the case, I'd inform him he didn't mark them virtual and override them so it wouldnt call the base class method (polymorphism).

Comment: i should have. At that time i was confused...:-( :-(

Comment: @user2681446: you should never giveup, i think he concentrated more on your confidence rather than technical stuff, you should have explained him clearly.

Comment: As soon as i told the answer he told me clear the area and thank you for coming. Mmm...U r right

Comment: I would consider it a blessing in disguise. Do you really want to work with that sort of developer?

Comment: You know what? Feel secure in the fact that you're probably better off working for someone else ;-)

Comment: Email him the link to this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct; there is no method overriding applied due to the absence of `virtual` and `override` keywords.

So in all three cases it returns output `A`.

If you want to apply proper method overriding, you need to apply `virtual` to the base class methods and `override` to the child class methods where you are overriding base class method.

Try This:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetName());

        a = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetName());

        a = new C();
        Console.WriteLine(a.GetName());
    }
}
public class A
{
    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "B";
    }
}
public class C : B
{
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "C";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning all objects (`new A()`, `new B()`, `new C()`) to the variable `A a`. Since they are all being viewed as type `A` and the method is not virtual, then the implementation for type `A` is invoked and "A" is returned.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides a more detailed explanation with samples.

Comment: It was a reputed multinational company and they have banned me for 6 months. Because i do not know the basics..!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B : A
{
   public string GetName()
   {
      return "B";
   }
}
```

is same as

```
public class B : A
{
   public new string GetName()
   {
      return "B";
   }
}
```

which will hide the method by calling the interface or baseclass,

var b = new B();
b.GetName() ==> "B"

while

A a = new B();
a.GetName() ===> "A"

this is dangrous and I saw lots of people write such code without knowing what's the difference between new and override